# Writing As a Transformation of the Reciprocal Parent Function

Tags: functions

> Write $y=\frac{2}{3x-6}$ in the form $y=\frac{k}{x-b}+c$

Supposedly simple, but how do you remove the coefficient of x in the denominator and get c? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a factor of $3$ out of the denominator. $c$ may be zero.

Comment: I still don't quite understand what the end result should be?

Comment: It is awkwardly phrased. Write $\frac 2 {3x - 6} = \frac 2 {3(x - 2)} = \frac {\frac 2 3} {x - 2}$ then k, b, c = ?